# How to Calculate the size of the given code using Halsted’s Metric?

Tags: c++

When I execute below code it gives me this message

Error - At least one public class is required in main file

Here is the link of the [program](https://onlinegdb.com/BJgW8sS-QP).

```
    #include <iostream.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    
    void main() {
        int a, b, c;
        int sum = 0;
        int sub;
        float prod = 1;
        float div;
        if (12 < a < 20)
            sum = a + b + c;
        else if (b > 30)
            sub = b - c;
        else if (10 < c < 18)
            prod = a * b;
        else
            div = c / a;
        cout <<” The values of sum, sub, prod and div are :”<< sum << sub << prod << div;
        getch();
    }
```

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main()`.  `(12 < a < 20)` should be `(12 < a && a < 20)`.  It appears you could use a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/4641116).

Comment: Are you compiling with a c++ compiler? You need `<iostream>`, not `<iostream.h>`

Comment: The code appears to be C++ (albeit not quite well-formed).  Why the `c` and `java` tags?

Comment: @cigien I am compiling with online "onlinegdb" complier.

Comment: There is a "share" button there. Add a link to that to your question.

Comment: @Eljay I am new to this platform i just sign up.

Comment: @cigien added link to above question.

Comment: I tried your link, and I'm getting completely different error messages, regarding `cout` not being available, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not sure what does your code do, but there are lots of logical & syntactical errors:**

1. Seemingly you're using a deprecated compiler because `iostream.h` is no longer used.
2. The values of the variables `a`, `b` & `c` are kept uninitialized, thus, it contains some garbage values.
3. The syntax:

   ```
   if (10 < c < 18)
   ```

   is incorrect. The correct idea should be:

   ```
   if (10 < c && c > 18)
   ```
4. The token `”` is unknown and cannot be used.
5. The declaration of the main function:

   ```
   void main() {}
   ```

   is incorrect as well. The right way to do it is:

   ```
   int main(void) {}
   ```

---

Assuming the value of `a` is initialized to 1, because if the values of `b` & `c` are kept zero (probably you want it), the `else` condition will take place, i.e. division of `c` with `a`, which yields illegal instruction error.

After solving these issues, the correct code would look like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
  // All the variables must be initialized if they are going to be used
  int a = 1, b = 0, c = 0;

  int sum = 0;
  int sub = 0;
  float prod = 1;
  float div = 0;

  if (12 < a && a > 20)
    sum = a + b + c;
  else if (b > 30)
    sub = b - c;
  else if (10 < c && c > 18)
    prod = a * b;
  else
    div = c / a;

  std::cout << "The values of sum, sub, prod and div are :"
            << sum << sub << prod << div << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```